# align listview to the center

Tags: android, listview, padding

I have an android application that uses a custom listview. All I want to do is to make this listview aligning center and not filling all the window (horizontal). for that purpose I set padding

```
 list.setPadding(20, 0, 20, 0);
    list.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
```

I want to set up a background color for space that listview in and another background for the padding space. when I write the above code only on click the main content background returning to black. How do I accomplish that? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check if using [margins](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams.html) solves your problem.